# Crystal Reports Maximum for date and string

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I'm having some trouble with a report I am building.

table1 is a main table that  has information like dates and integers. table2 is the look up table for table1 which is linked by the integar to table 2 ID, which gives the value of the table1 integar.

table1 has data such as:
1/1/2018 - 1
2/1/2018 - 2

table2 has data such as
1 = Active
2 = Inactive

So the goal of this report is to find the most recent status. i have my select expert group as table1.date = maximum({table1.date}, {@group}) and my select expert record as table2.status = "Active".

What the report pulls is the most recent "Active" status. I need it to only pull the "Active" status, if that is the most recent status and not print the "Inactive" ones.

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula called {@Date_And_Status} that combines the Date and the Status:

`ToText({table1.date}, "yyyyMMdd") & {table2.status}`

In your Group Selection formula, use:

```
maximum({@Date_And_Status}, {@group}) = ToText(maximum({table1.date}, {@group}), "yyyyMMdd") & "Active"
```